# is there some way to view the stack of a particular process?

Tags: linux, debugging

I want to view the stack of a particular process in linux. It could be any process.
I know that GDB could help, but I guess you need the source code to analyse the output.

Comment: what about using the `/proc/pid/` information?

Comment: @Fredrik: there is a lot of information in `/proc/<pid>/`, but you simply cannot "view the stack" of another process unless you are attached to it with the debugging API. Otherwise programs could just snoop other programs data at will, and that would be bad :-P.

Comment: can we create an debug version of linux kernel which will print out whats in the stack ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is with either a debugger or the debugging API (`ptrace` for linux).

Basically what you want to do is:

- attach to the process (`PTRACE_ATTACH`)
- get the thread context (`PTRACE_GETREGS`)
- from the thread context get the value of the stack pointer (likely `esp` or `rsp`)
- read memory from the process using ptrace, starting at the address of the stack pointer (`PTRACE_PEEKDATA` or `/proc/<pid>/mem`)
- detach from the process (`PTRACT_DETACH`)

From there, the analysis is pretty much up to you. You may want to check out my debugger [edb](http://codef00.com/projects#debugger). For more details, of course you should [`man ptrace`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man2/ptrace.2.html)